# User Experiences for Visual Studio 2008 extensions for SharePoint v1.3 CTP

Tags: sharepoint

In January, [MS released a CTP of VS Extensions for SharePoint v1.3.](http://weblogs.asp.net/jan/archive/2009/01/12/visual-studio-2008-extensions-for-windows-sharepoint-services-1-3-ctp.aspx)  Has anyone used these?  What have your experiences been?

We used the previous version and did not like how much was hidden/abstracted from the developers.  We eventually abandoned the extensions and create our own WSP's with MakeCab.exe.

...Peter

Comment: hmm.. How did I miss this!!! Will be installing it over the weekend, and will let you know my feedback.. But hey, it works on x64!!!!! :)

Answer (score 0):

The install of the website that runs the webservices completely failed and I could never get it to work so I uninstalled it.

Comment: I've also had some problems with the installation of VSeWSS 1.3. The web service gave me an error message about an authentication problem. The reason for this was, that the web service couldn't resolve my PC's name properly. But a little bit thinking and hosts file editing did the job.

Answer (score 0):

Till today I didn't encounter any problems with VSeWSS 1.3. except some issues with the VSeWSS's web service, which were related to a name resolving problem of my PC.